# Using AngularJS $resource to get data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use $resource to get data from a static json file and here is the code snippet :

```
 angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory('profilelist',function($resource){
    return $resource('services/profiles/profilelist.json',{},{
        query:{method:'GET'}
    });
});
```

In the controller,

```
function ProfileCtrl($scope,profilelist) {
$scope.items = [];
$scope.profileslist = profilelist.query();
for (var i=0;i<=$scope.profileslist.length;i++){
    if($scope.profileslist[i] && $scope.profileslist[i].profileid){
        var temp_profile = $scope.profileslist[i].profileid;
    }
    $scope.items.push(temp_profile);

}
```

But now, I am facing an error : 
`TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'`

Could you please help me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure, but notice that .query() is not a synchronous operation, meaning you cannot iterate over the results immediately.

Comment: You are right. I used a callback to iterate over the results.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to specify actions parameter for default `$resource` methods (these are 'get', 'save', 'query', 'remove', 'delete'). In this case you can use `.query()` method as is (this requires only service definition to be chaged):

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory('profilelist',function($resource){
    return $resource('services/profiles/profilelist.json');
  });
```

P.S. And one more hint is that your example unwrapped json into hash rather then array (that's why you received no push method error), if you need it to be an array set `isArray: true` to action config:

```
'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
```

And as @finishingmove spotted you really can't assign [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) result to obtain immediately, provide callback:

```
$scope.profileslist = profilelist.query(function (response) {
    angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
        if (item.profileid) {
            $scope.items.push(item.profileid);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry Evseev. I tried the following code as well and it worked,but your answer is easier !     `angular.module('upe.services', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Profileslst', function($resource){
        return $resource('services/profiles/:profileid.json', {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{profileid:'profilelist'}, isArray:true}
        });
    });`